Which version of io.appium:java-client is compatible with selenium-java 4.25.0 to resolve NoSuchMethodError?
I am getting the following error when invoking MobileDriver with Selenium Java 4.25.0 and Appium Java Client 8.3.0:
Error screenshot
When I click the error line number in logs, the following screen is displayed:
Class File not found
I tried using the latest Appium Java Client 9.3.0, as well as other versions in the 9.x.x series from Maven Repository, with Selenium Java 4.25.0. However, I am still encountering the same issue.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<init>(java.net.URI, java.time.Duration, java.time.Duration, org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter, java.net.Proxy, org.openqa.selenium.Credentials)' 

Example code:
// MobileLogin.java file    
public void invokeMobileDriver(String remoteTestName) {
        baseClass.driver = baseClass.invokeMobileDriver("AD", remoteTestName);
    }
// BaseClass.java file
// Method to invoke mobile driver
    public AppiumDriver invokeMobileDriver(String appType, String testNameForReomoteExec) {
        if (appiumDriver != null) {
            try {
                this.appiumDriver.close(); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (appType.equalsIgnoreCase("LP")) {
            appiumDriver =  new MobileDriverFactory().invokeMobileDriver("LP",testNameForReomoteExec);
        } else if (appType.equalsIgnoreCase("AD")) {
            appiumDriver =  new MobileDriverFactory().invokeMobileDriver("AD",testNameForReomoteExec);
        } else {
            //exit from execution
        }
        initializeMobileDriver(appiumDriver);
        return appiumDriver;
    }

// MobileDriverFactory.java file

public AppiumDriver invokeMobileDriver(String appType, String testNameForReomoteExec) { 
        // Created object of DesiredCapabilities class.
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        try {
            HashMap<String, Object> ltOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Environment.mobileDevicePlatformName);
            if (appType.equalsIgnoreCase("LP")) {
                capabilities.setCapability("appPackage",Environment.outplacementAndroidAppPackage);
                capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", Environment.outplacementAndroidAppActivity);
            }
            if (appType.equalsIgnoreCase("AD")) {
                capabilities.setCapability("appPackage",Environment.caAppPackageForAndroid);
                capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", Environment.caAppActivityForAndroid);
            }
    if (Environment.mobileDevicePlatformName.equalsIgnoreCase("android")) {
                if (Environment.mobileDeviceLocation.equalsIgnoreCase("local")) {
                    
                    // Set android deviceName desired capability. Set your device name.
                    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", Environment.mobileDeviceName);
                    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_VERSION, Environment.mobileDevicePlatformVersion);
                    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Environment.mobileDevicePlatformName);
                    capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
return new AndroidDriver(new URL(Environment.androidRemoteDriverURL), capabilities);
}

